# Can I label months in a ggplot with the initial of each month and maintain the order?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to extract the calendar month from sales data and plot results to a barplot.

Using dplyr and lubridate, I create a new variables SalesMonth as a factor by coding SalesMonth = as.factor(month(SaleDate). This return values 1 - 12 which I can then plot on the barplot.

For the final plot, I would like to display the value JFMAMJJASOND instead of 1 - 12. Is this possible? How should I go about this - in the dplyr data preparation step, or directly labelling the values in the ggplot?

I have looked at the applying levels to my factor statement and using month.abb but it is not working.  Specifically I want to use just the first letter, so there will be duplicates (3 Js, 2 As, 2 Ms) if I tried to create a factor.

Comment: I know you got an answer, but it would be helpful for future people with this question to add a [mcve] of your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your month values are `numeric` then you can do this at the plotting stage by modifying the labels. In your `ggplot` add the following:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, 
                     labels = c('J', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J', 'J', 'A', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D'))
```

If they are not numeric then you can simply convert them using `as.numeric()` before plotting... or simply remove the factor conversion from your original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
factor(SalesMonth, levels = c("Ja","F","Mar","A","M",
                              "Ju","Jl","A","S","O","N","D"))
```

If you use unique abbreviations, it will preserve order for ggplot

Comment: I think you want to set the `labels` not the `levels`